# Finding the values of $ x$ and $y$

Tags: matrices

I have two matrices 
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} &  0 \\ 
 0&   x
\end{bmatrix} $ and $B= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
 y&1  
\end{bmatrix}$ that multiply to give: 
$AB=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} &0   \\ 
1 &\frac{1}{4}  
\end{bmatrix}$

However I am having problems fining the values for $x$ and $y$. Can you please help me calculate the values for $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Jut multiply the two matrices keeping the parameters $x,y$, and compare the results.

Answer (score 1):

$AB = \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & x 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
y & 1 
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
x y & x 
\end{pmatrix}$

Given that $ \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
x y & x 
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
1 & \frac{1}{4} 
\end{pmatrix} $

$\implies x y = 1 $ and $ x = \frac{1}{4}$

$\implies x = \frac{1}{4} , y = 4$

Answer (score 0):

The really fast way to find $x$ is by noting that the determinant of a product is the product of the determinants. Then to find $y$ you can just compute the bottom-left entry of the product in terms of $y$.